# Django JQuery Ajax events not triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-admin

i extended my django-admin detail site with some javascript magic...,
before an ajax requests gets sent, i want to manipulate it with global ajax beforeSend handler, my setup:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    <script>
        django.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('a')
            django.jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    console.log('b')
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

What happens:

Console prints

```
a
```

but it doesnt print

```
b
```

Can anybody explain it to me or help me out?

I read almost every documentation, but there is no hint why my *beforeSend* is not executed.

Greetings and thanks !

Comment: Are you issuing an Ajax request? beforeSend is executed when you send a request, in fact it is executed before each ajax request, but wont by itself when jquery is ready